# Loading Image into document.body Background

Tags: javascript, css, image, dom

I'm attempting to pull an image (in this case, `/camera/frame`, which is a known-good JPG), and load it as the background of my `document.body`.

Here's my code thus far:

```
var backgroundImage = new Image();
backgroundImage.onload = function ()
{
    console.log("onload");
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = this.src;
};

backgroundImage.src = 'camera/frame';
```

`"onload"` prints as expected, and this.src prints out the full URL to `/camera/frame`, however `document.body.style.backgroundImage` remains `""`.

Comment: `document.body.style.background='url('+this.src+')';`

Comment: But then what's the point of loading the `Image` object? Couldn't I just do `document.body.style.background=url("camera/frame");`?

Comment: yes absolutely -- you don't need the image

Comment: but the reason i'm using the `Image` is so that it will load/cache the image before trying to draw it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canvas 2D to the rescue!

```
var backgroundImage = new Image();
backgroundImage.onload = function ()
{    
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    canvas.width = this.width;
    canvas.height = this.height;

    var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvasContext.drawImage(this, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
};

backgroundImage.src = 'camera/frame'; 
backgroundImage.width = $(window).width();
backgroundImage.height = $(window).height();
```

Loads the image in the background, then draws it into the canvas seamlessly!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may be missing two things.

```
var path = 'path/to/image.jpg';
document.body.style.background='url('+path+')';
```